# terraform statefile is locked how do I unlock it

Tags: terraform, terraform-state

I am trying to use basic terraform commands like `plan`, but cannot because the terraform state is locked (see below.)

I know I am the only person or process interacting with this terraform instance, and see my name in the `Who` line of the lock below.  I think this probably happened when I pressed `Ctrl-C` on a terraform prompt.

How do I unlock it?

```
$ terraform plan
╷   
│ Error: Error acquiring the state lock
│   
│ Error message: ConditionalCheckFailedException: The conditional request failed
│ Lock Info:
│   ID:        xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx
│   Path:      xxx 
│   Operation: OperationTypePlan
│   Who:       xxx 
│   Version:   1.3.4
│   Created:   2022-11-15 19:51:21.368168706 +0000 UTC 
│   Info:           
│   
│   
│ Terraform acquires a state lock to protect the state from being written
│ by multiple users at the same time. Please resolve the issue above and try 
│ again. For most commands, you can disable locking with the "-lock=false"
│ flag, but this is not recommended.
╵
```

Comment: Can you edit your question to share the full error please?

Answer (score 78):

You can manually unlock the state using the [force-unlock](https://www.terraform.io/docs/commands/force-unlock.html) command :

```
terraform force-unlock LOCK_ID
```

The lock ID is generally shown in the error message.

It may not work if your state is local and locked by a local process. If it is the case, try killing that process and retry.

Comment: Can you please explain the way to kill the process ?? And when error is occurred, as you said we are not getting the lock Id So, what is the solution in that case??

Comment: Is your state local?

Comment: YES, My state is local

Comment: Is there any solution for that ?

Comment: @AmitSharma just try kill process or terminate the shell as Local state files cannot be unlocked by another process.

Comment: If it is local process, you will need to kill the process (from task manager in case of windows)and delete the state file from your local folder terraform.tfstate. This will help to remove the lock

Comment: How to programmatically retrieve the LOCK_ID?

Comment: @SamLee If the state is Lock, you should see the lock id in the terraform cmd output when you execute a command that affect the plan.

Answer (score 8):

To unlock the state without having to type confirmation:

```
terraform force-unlock -force LOCK_ID
```

Answer (score 1):

If your TF state file is saved on the storage account in azure or S3 bucket, you can navigate to that file and unlock as shown below (example is for azure storage location in container.)

[image]

Comment: Good tip, that lead me to just removing the `terraform.tfstate` files from my DynamoDB lock table.